# problem with FlightRadarAPI library, 'flight' is not defined

Tags: python

I started using the [FlightRadar API library](https://pypi.org/project/FlightRadarAPI/). I have a problem when I write:

```
from FlightRadar24.api import FlightRadar24API

fr_api = FlightRadar24API()
details = fr_api.get_flight_details(flight.id)
flight.set_flight_details(details)

print("Flying to", flight.destination_airport_name)

details = fr_api.get_flight_details(flight.id)
# => NameError: name 'flight' is not defined
```

I can't understand what is `flight.id` and what to write there.

Comment: You never define `flight` - perhaps you need to get it from `fr_api`?

Comment: yes, thanks, I didn't use fr_api, but i don't understand what is flight.id and where I can take it

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the id of your flight from somewhere, e.g. from `fr_api.get_flights()`. Try the following:

```
from FlightRadar24.api import FlightRadar24API

fr_api = FlightRadar24API()

for flight in fr_api.get_flights():
    details = fr_api.get_flight_details(flight.id)
    flight.set_flight_details(details)
    print(f"Flying (id {flight.id}) is to {flight.destination_airport_name}")
```

Comment: sry, but i don't understand, can you give me example with any example "flight.id"?

Comment: See the updated program that now outputs flight ids as well.

Comment: Thanks, I have 2 questions left, if you answer, I will be grateful. 1) how to find out the ID of a specific flight. 2) what data can be obtained using flight, is there any list?

Comment: Update: Now, you don't need to pass the `flight.id` anymore. Just give the flight object to the method as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
from FlightRadar24 import FlightRadar24API

class Flight:
    def __init__(self, flight_id):
        self.id = flight_id


fr_api = FlightRadar24API()
        
# Create a Flight object
id='3356c572' # Id can be obtained from the flight's share link e.g https://www.flightradar24.com/EVA087/3356c572
flight = Flight(id)
flight_details = fr_api.get_flight_details(flight)

print(flight_details)
```